# How to get product collection along with is saleable attribute in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, products, product-collection, stock-availability

I'm using magento v2.4.1 and I'm extending `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` in my custom module block to load a custom product collection like this:

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
    if ($this->_productCollection === null) {
     // \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory 
     $productCollectionFactory,
     $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
     $collection->addAttributeToFilter('price',['gt'=>0]); 
     $collection->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true);
     $categoryId = $this->getCategoryId();
     $categoryProductTable = $collection->getResource()->getTable('catalog_category_product');
     $collection->getSelect()->where('e.entity_id IN (SELECT product_id FROM '.$categoryProductTable.' WHERE category_id = '.$categoryId.')');
     $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array(
      \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE ,
      \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG ,
      \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH ,
      \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH ,
     ));
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
   }
   return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

I need to print if the product is saleable or not in .phtml, so i tried to do it like this:

```
foreach($productCollection as $product){
  echo $product->isSaleable() ? 'Saleable' : 'Not Saleable';
}
```

the above code always print Saleable, even though some of the product is not saleable, but if i load the product by id, it will print correctly:

```
// i add this in block function
public function getProductById($productId){
  return $this->productFactory->create()->load($productId);
}

// in .phtml i call it like this
foreach($productCollection as $product){
  $product = $this->getProductById($product->getId());
  echo $product->isSaleable() ? 'Saleable' : 'Not Saleable';
}
```

I'm trying to avoid to use this load product by id, because it might take a lot of mysql connection if i load huge amount of product collection, how can i achieve to load a product collection along with is saleable functionality ??

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the collection to get only products in stock with the flag for `has_stock_status_filter`:

```
$collection = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId)
                ->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true);
```

And, there is option

```
Is_available()
```

You can use it as your requirements.